# What should I do about a "hopeless" question?

Tags: discussion

[Trying to prove that two angles are congruent in a isosceles trapezoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866177/trying-to-prove-that-two-angles-are-congruent-in-a-isosceles-trapezoid) is a question that is about a month old, and has 32 views. It has about 4 comments, and that's it. I call it "hopeless", because I can't really do much or even give it a bounty.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should either

1. find a way to substantially improve the question through an edit, or
2. earn some more reputation and then bounty it.

One suggestion I have for the first bullet is to fully type out the text in your image.  It is difficult to read in its current state, and it seems reasonable to conclude that that is why the question has received poor traffic.

Comment: @user3758041:  On my pathetic (but cheap) 10 inch screen, I cannot read the text. The result is standard, if the text had been fully legible, there would probably have quickly been at least one answer.

Comment: Hm, your suggestion to type the text is a great idea. I think that's exactly what I'll do.

Comment: @user3758041 OK, ping me when you do and I'll bounty it for you, too.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I just edited the answer, and it's ready to go.